# trouble styling my google map

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to style my google map all week and am going round in circles! I have the JSON values I want to use but no idea how to add them into the javascript! I also want to make the zoom bar control thing sit on the right of the window rather than on the left as my map is a full page background so on the left this is hidden behind the site content divs.

Can anyone help?

:)

The JSON I want to add are:

[ { stylers: [ { saturation: -90 }, { gamma: 0.87 } ] } ]

And the code I have for my map is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) { 

  // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
  // Dont try to unroll this function. It has to be here for the function closure
  // Each instance of the function preserves the contends of a different instance
  // of the "marker" and "html" variables which will be needed later when the event triggers.    
  function createMarker(point,html) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    return marker;
  }

  // Display the map, with some controls and set the initial location 
  var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
  map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
  map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(50.826910965853585, -0.13648152351379395), 16);




  // Set up the markers with info windows 

  var point = new GLatLng(50.826910965853585, -0.13648152351379395);
  var marker = createMarker(point,'<div style="width:300px">text for pop up here....</div>')
  map.addOverlay(marker);





}







// display a warning if the browser was not compatible
else {
  alert("Sorry, the Google Maps API is not compatible with this browser");
}

// This Javascript is based on code provided by the
// Community Church Javascript Team
// http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: this guys blog has  alot of examples on google maps http://www.svennerberg.com

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var myStyles = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    stylers: [ { saturation: -90 }, { gamma: 0.87 }
  }
];

map.setOptions({styles: myStyles });
```

Based on: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html#styling_the_default_map

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to use Maps API V2, which does not provide you with the ability to style your map. As graphicdivine mentioned, this code will help you style a Maps API V3 map:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html#styling_the_default_map

You should be switching over anyway since V2 is deprecated. To get started with a V3 map, check out the [Maps API Basics page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html).

Comment: thanks so much for the feedback, I thought I was using V3 d'oh!